# Plotting coefficients in Stata

Tags: plot, stata

I followed

https://www.stata.com/meeting/germany14/abstracts/materials/de14_jann.pdf

to plot coefficients of age.

I did

```
logit Y i.age
eststo plotplot
coefplot plotplot
```

But the plot has age on vertical axis, and coefficient on horizontal axis. It should be the opposite.

Also, I only want the coefficients of age, not constant or anything else. How do I do that?

And does "at" command work for discretized explanatory variable like i.age ?  Or is it the case that it just takes so much time (I had to stop it because it was taking so much time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logit coefficients are not particularly interpretable, so it is not clear why you want to plot them. There is also no `at` command, though the `margins` command has an `at()` option. If you do want the index function coefficients, just omit the `margins` step from below. `coefplot` and `marginsplot` do very similar things, though `coefplot` is considerably more flexible.

I am guessing you have something in mind like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
xtile mpg_tercile = mpg, nq(3)
logit foreign i.mpg_tercile weight
margins, dydx(mpg_tercile) at(weight = 3000) post
coefplot, vertical
marginsplot, recast(scatter)
```

This calculates the average marginal effect of falling in the middle or top third of the mile per gallon distribution on the probability of the car being foreign with weight of 3000.

Comment: Thank you! "vertical" did the trick. By the way, how can I prevent having coefficients of other variables (including constant) printed on the graphs? Also, x-axis looks http://prntscr.com/iefask  so I need to change them to just numbers like 1,2,3...  Do you know how to do that? Thank you again!

Comment: Try `coefplot, vertical keep(*.mpg_tercile) coeflabels(2.mpg_tercile = "Middle Third" 3.mpg_tercile = "Top Third")`. This can all be found by typing `help coefplot`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know I could have regex inside keep!!

Comment: For the coeflabels, I tried     "coefplot, vertical keep(*.age) coeflabels(19.age="19" 20.age="20" 21.age="21" 22.age="22" 23.age="23")"    and this seems to work but I have age until 70 or possibly even more. Can I somehow shorten the code? Thank you again!

Comment: You can write that out with a loop and stick it into a local that you use in `coeflabel()`, but it it probably easiest to just use `xlabel(19(10)70)` instead of `coeflabel()'.

Comment: @Masterov  Thank you!